# How to generate a random alphanumeric string of 16 characters in Java using SecureRandom

Tags: java, android, string, biginteger, alphanumeric

I am trying to generate an alphanumeric string using SecureRandom.

Here is my little code :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class GenerateSecureRandom {
  private static SecureRandom SECURE_RANDOM = new SecureRandom();

  public static String nextSessionId() {
     return new BigInteger(64, SECURE_RANDOM).toString(16);
  }
}
```

It works ! I get for example this : 7c52cfce6c479803  = 16 characters : OK !

My problem is that **sometimes** this code returns a string of 15 characters and I do not understand why. (I'm a beginner...)

Here is an example :  515c38584d0a077 = 15 characters : ERROR

What am I doing wrong ?

I am beginner in Java programming, so please be indulgent if my way of proceeding is not correct :)

If this code is not correct, how can I get the expected result? I would like to use SecureRandom.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Sorry if my question is duplicated, I searched without finding an answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`BigInteger` constructor you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-) takes a *maximum* bit length.

> Constructs a randomly generated BigInteger, uniformly distributed over the range 0 to (2<sup>numBits - 1</sup>), inclusive.
>
> **Parameters:**
> `numBits` - maximum bitLength of the new BigInteger.

You may more rarely get strings even less than 15 characters long.

This occurs because the most significant bit(s) may be zero, resulting in a hexadecimal number that doesn't *need* a full 16 characters to be represented.  Notice how none of the strings you generate start with `0`.

If there are less than 16 characters, then prepend `'0'` characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! That suits me